# Is it possible to return a list of a class in celery?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have a question about Celery.
I am calling a function named task and I want to return a list of a specific class.
But if I do this I get an error on my server:

```
No module named 'modelsgert'
```

modelsgert is the name of the python file where my class has been defined.
I have imported the same file to my project that is located on my server but yet he doesn't know this. Probably he sends a reference to the file location of the file on the celery server.

code celery server:

```
from celery import Celery
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from modelsgert import(
Diagnose,
Procedur,
DBSession,
Data
)
import time
celery = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@celery.task()
def test_task(data):
    diagnose = DBSession.query(Diagnose)
    listofdiagnoses = []
    listofdiagnoses.append(diagnose[0])
    listofdiagnoses.append(diagnose[1])
    return (listofdiagnoses)
```

code Pyramid server

```
celery = Celery( backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@192.168.1.5:5672//')
    celery.conf.update(CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp', BROKER_HOST='192.168.1.5', BROKER_USER='kristof', BROKER_PASSWORD='bob', BROKER_VHOST='myvhost', BROKER_PORT=5672)
    task = celery.send_task('tasks.test_task',["kakker"])
    TheData = task.get()
```

is there a way to fix this problem in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that `modelsgert` is available when you see that error?

Celery uses pickle by default, and that module indeed stores the the *name* of the module and class (together with the data contained in the class), and when loading the data again, the module and class are looked up dynamically. This stage fails because the `modelsgert` cannot be imported.

I must note that you are trying to send SQLAlchemy objects here, and that is very rarely a good idea. The objects are tied to a specific session, and when you unpickle the objects that session will no longer be there. Moveover, the objects represent database state, and the database state could easily have *changed* by the time you load the objects again.

You should, instead, send object *identifiers*, and query for the objects again on the other side. Instead of a list of `Diagnose` objects, send the primary keys instead:

```
listofdiagnoses = [d.id for d in diagnose]
```

On the other side, you'd then use those identifiers to load your `Diagnose` objects again from the database.

Comment: I think the pyramid project knows modelsgert because in the beginning of my file I added the code: from .modelsgert import *

Comment: @KristofDochez: and that works? What is the full traceback? When does the error happen? Is it on your Pyramid web server, or on your Celery workers?

Comment: on my Pyramid web server. but I forgot to add a dot before modelsgert  in my previous post. I edited now. does this mather?

Comment: @KristofDochez: Yes, that is a different import. That is relative to the current package. Your error seems to imply that the other import is a global one. That is a *different* module then, and the error certainly makes sense. How did you add your project to the Celery setup?

Comment: I just copy pasted the file modelsgert to the Celery project and imported it.

Comment: @KristofDochez: Don't. Share the same package between your Pyramid server and the Celery server. At the very least, give it the same *full* name, so include the same top-level package. In Pyramid, it is called `yourpackage.modelsgert`, on your Celery server it is now called `modelsgert`. That is a *big* difference.